# Why the space appears as sub string in this split instruction?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string with spaces and some non-informative characters and substrings required to be excluded and just to keep some important sections. I used the split as below:

```
String myString[]={"01: Hi       you look tired today?  Can I help you?"};
myString=myString[0].split("[\\s+]");// Split based on any white spaces
for(int ii=0;ii<myString.length;ii++) 
    System.out.println(myString[ii]);
```

The result is :

```
01:
Hi






you
look
tired
today?

Can
I
help
you?
```

The spaces appeared after the split as sub strings when the regex is “[\s+]” but disappeared when the regex is "\s+". I am confused and not able to find answer in the related stack overflow pages. The link [regex-Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) made me more confused. 
Please help, I am new with java.

```
19/1/2015:Edit
```

After your valuable advice, I reached to point in my program where a conditional statements is required to be decomposed and processed. The case I have is:

```
String s1="01:IF   rd.h && dq.L && o.LL && v.L THEN la.VHB , av.VHR with 0.4610;";
String [] s2=s1.split(("[\\s\\&\\,]+"));
for(int ii=0;ii<s2.length;ii++)System.out.println(s2[ii]);
```

The result is fine till now as:

```
01:IF
rd.h
dq.L
o.LL
v.L
THEN
la.VHB
av.VHR
with
0.4610;
```

My next step is to add string "with" to the regex  and get rid of this word  while doing the split.
I tried it this way:

```
String s1="01:IF   rd.h && dq.L && o.LL && v.L THEN la.VHB , av.VHR with 0.4610;";
String [] s2=s1.split(("[\\s\\&\\, with]+"));
for(int ii=0;ii<s2.length;ii++)System.out.println(s2[ii]);
```

The result not perfect, because I got unwonted extra split at every "h" letter as:

```
01:IF
rd.
dq.L
o.LL
v.L
THEN
la.VHB  
av.VHR
0.4610;
```

Any advice on how to  specify string with mixed white spaces and separation marks?
Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: Go read `String.split()`'s documentation. And then write your `println` to include the length of the strings as you print them. You will find they aren't spaces, they are empty. Maybe that helps your understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest problem is not understanding enough about regular expressions to write them properly. One key point you don't comprehend is that `[...]` is a *character class*, which is a list of characters any one of which can match. For example:

- `[abc]` matches either a, b or c (it does not match "abc")
- `[\\s+]` matches any whitespace or "+" character
- `[with]` matches a single character that is either w, i, t or h
- `[.$&^?]` matches those literal characters - most characters lose their special regex meaning when in a character class

To split on any number of whitespace, comma and ampersand and consume "with" (if it appears), do this:

```
String [] s2 = s1.split("[\\s,&]+(with[\\s,&]+)?");
```

You can try it easily here [Online Regex](https://regex101.com/r/mB4nA5/1#pcre) and get useful comments.

Comment: So many options,..... I suggest alternative way as : String [] s2 = s1.split("[\\s,&]+(with)*?"); is there any wrong with it ? Thanks.

Comment: I used the form :String [] s2 = s1.split("([\\d]{2,3}?(:IF))?[\\s,&]+(with)*?"); to elemental the "01:IF" from my string too But i get, space as  first element in the splitted string array s2. How can i get rid of the extra generated space element? Thanks.

Comment: @java the regex in your first comment won't consume the space (or comma etc)  after the "with". Your second comment is a different question: ask a new one

Answer (score 2):

inside square brackets, `[\s+]` will represent the whitespace character class with the plus sign added. it is only one character so a sequence of spaces will split many empty strings as Todd noted, and will also use `+` as separator.

you should use `\s+` (without brackets) as the separator. that means one or more whitespace characters.

```
myString=myString[0].split("\\s+");
```

Comment: The point is `[...]` is a character class and the regex has no quantifier, so it will split on every single space (or plus). Remove the square brackets - a character class is not wanted/needed here.